# NG0303: Can't bind to X since it isn't a known property of Y

Tags: angular, jasmine

Recently I upgraded my application to Angular 17

this error is only happening when I issue test command

```
ng test
```

Application build and execution works properly and it went to production everything is fine there,
only in jasmine testing I am blocked, is anyone faced similar issue let me know the fix

Angular 17.0.0 code

---

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      imports: [
          CommonModule,
          BrowserModule,
          AppModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Error coming from

```
at reportUnknownPropertyError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:9036:15)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by duplicating the module code `app.module.ts` to `app.module.spec.ts`

and introduce `schema` section with `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` as below

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientXsrfModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and use this new module in jasmine code

```
import { AppModule } from './app.module.spec';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      errorOnUnknownProperties: false,
      imports: [
        AppModule
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are assigning type `TestComponent` to the `component` variable but in reality you are creating `HeaderComponent`. When assigning the `fixture.componentInstance` there is a type mismatch. To fix it, just create the right component:

```js
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
```

The currently accepted answer just ignores the issue and is not advisable. It will not make the component testable.

Comment: the question is not related component types and generics, it is related a `NG0303` error code of typescript compiler detects `ngFor*` as an invalid attribute for any HTML tag only in jasmine